# Paginação não funciona com argumento Offset Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, paginação

Eu preciso listar os posts no **index.php** e quero pular três posts recentes. Mas ao navegar na paginação ela não avança nos números e nem muda as postagens. Ou melhor dizendo, a paginação não funciona quando tento pular esses 3 posts recentes.

No **functions.php**:

```
function wp_pagination($pages = '', $range = 9)
{  
    global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;  
    $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;  
    $pagination = array(  
        'base' => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),  
        'format' => '',  
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,  
        'current' => $current,  
        'show_all' => true,  
        'type' => 'plain'  
    );  
    if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() ) $pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 's', get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ) ) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged' );  
    if ( !empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']) ) $pagination['add_args'] = array( 's' => get_query_var( 's' ) );  
    echo '<div class="wp_pagination">'.paginate_links( $pagination ).'</div>';
}
```

No **index.php**:

```
<?php global $query_string; parse_str( $query_string, $my_query_array ); 
$paged = ( isset( $my_query_array['paged'] ) && !empty( $my_query_array['paged'] ) ) ? $my_query_array['paged'] : 1; 
query_posts("posts_per_page=10&offset=3paged=$paged"); ?> 

<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


<a href="<?php the_Permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> </a>
<a href="<?php the_Permalink(); ?>"> <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2> </a>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<p><?php wp_pagination();?></p>

<?php else : ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Veja que estou utilizando o argumento `offset=3` para pular esses três posts e estou tentando fazer a paginação continuar funcionando mas até agora sem nenhum sucesso.

Comment: Jr17, português, por favor;

Comment: Desculpe-me @AndersonCarlosWoss eu não sei usar direito esse fórum e também não gosto de ficar fazendo perguntas como essas mas como eu já procurei a solução desse e não encontrei, e achei que aqui eu poderia obter essa ajuda.

Comment: @Jr17 A paginação funciona normalmente sem o Offset?

Comment: @Heathcliff sim ela funciona normalmente sem o offset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jr17, o erro se encontra no arquivo index.php

Bem aqui ó:

> query_posts("posts_per_page=10&offset=**3paged**=$paged");

O erro ali, é que você está usando o & para juntar o offset no posts_per_page, porém, você não está usando o & para conectar o paged com o ofsset, por esse motivo, o paged não funciona.

Troque a linha anterior por:

> query_posts("posts_per_page=10&offset=**3&paged**=$paged");

***OBS:*** A Lógica do Offset é que assim que a página abrir, ele vai pular 3 posts, ou seja, os 3 primeiros posts da página 1, os 3 primeiros posts da página 2 e etc, então ele sempre irá pular 3 posts em todas as páginas, se você deseja que ele pule apenas os 3 primeiros posts da **PRIMEIRA** página, você deve fazer um if pra lançar uma variavel offset

Algo assim:

```
<?php global $query_string; parse_str( $query_string, $my_query_array ); 
$paged = ( isset( $my_query_array['paged'] ) && !empty( $my_query_array['paged'] ) ) ? $my_query_array['paged'] : 1; 
// Define o offset como 0
$offset = "offset=0";
// Caso seja a página 1, define o offset como 3
if ($paged == 1) {
$offset = "offset=3";
}

query_posts("posts_per_page=10&$offset&paged=$paged"); ?>

<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


<a href="<?php the_Permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> </a>
<a href="<?php the_Permalink(); ?>"> <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2> </a>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<p><?php wp_pagination();?></p>

<?php else : ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: muito obrigado por sua ajuda, Fiquei muito feliz por ter me ajudado, No entanto fiz a modificações que vc fala e na paginação /1/ ele pula os três últmos posts mas quando eu vou para paginação /2/ e as demais ele volta a mostrar os 3 três primeiros prosts e todos os outros da pagina /1/ não importe o quanto eu avançe, Sendo assim eu aproveitei a sua lógica de usar o if como condicional da pagina /1/ e ele funcinou. E não repete na outras paginas. Eu mudei esse trecho assim: 

`if ($paged == 1) {
$offset = "offset=3";
}
query_posts("posts_per_page=10&$offset&paged=$paged"); ?>`
pode ser ?

Comment: @Jr17 Funcionando pra você é o que vale, amigo, não se preocupe Haha! Irei editar a minha resposta com o seu código alterado, se a resposta estiver certa, peço que indique ela como a resposta certa xD

Comment: tudo bem pode editar sim que eu indico.

Comment: Prontinho @Jr17 ;)